# 16 bit clock driven booth multiplier VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am attempting to program a clock driven 16bit booth multiplier in VHDL. Any multiplication where the result is a 15bit or less number is correct and anything above is junk values. Below is my architecture definition, I am trying to understand the error in my logic.

```
begin
    process(CLK, RST)
    variable a:std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    variable b:std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    variable s:std_logic_vector(32 downto 0) := "000000000000000000000000000000000";
    variable incre:integer:= 0; 
    variable valid1:std_logic:= '1';
        begin
            if RST = '1' then
                valid1 := '0';
                valid <= '0';
                s := "000000000000000000000000000000000";
                P <= "--------------------------------";
                a := M;
                s(16 downto 1) := Q;
            elsif rising_edge(CLK) and valid1 = '0' then
                incre := incre + 1;
                if(s(1) = '1' and s(0) = '0') then
                    b := (s(32 downto 17));
                    s(32 downto 17) := (b(15 downto 0) - a(15 downto 0));
                elsif (s(1) = '0' and s(0) = '1') then
                    b := (s(32 downto 17));
                    s(32 downto 17) := (b(15 downto 0) + a(15 downto 0));
                end if;
                s(31 downto 0) := s(32 downto 1);
            end if;
            if incre = 16 then
                P(31 downto 0) <= s(32 downto 1);
                valid1 := '1';
                valid <= '1';
                incre := 0;
            end if;
        end process;
```

Comment: Did you try setting `s(32) := '0'` at the end of the process?

Comment: I tried pushing in a 0 on the shift right but it did not seem to fix the problem. I am getting junk output for the P(31 downto 16), the shift right after checking my notes should keep the previous s(32) value

Comment: You've not provided a [mcve] demonstrating a specific problem with known values, expected and actual results. Note P, value1, value and incre are assigned outside the if statement evaluating the rising edge of CLK and they're all assigned reset values. incre is also assigned when the clock edge is evaluated. You are dependent on either package numeric_std_unsigned (-2008) or Synopsys std_logic_unsigned to provide arithmetic for std_logic_vector (that's okay, no relations are evaluated other than s(1 downto 0). Your method doesn't take into account the most negative multiplicand.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a complete example of your code...

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Booth16 is
    port (
        CLK   : in  std_logic;
        RST   : in  std_logic;
        M     : in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        Q     : in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        valid : out std_logic;
        P     : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
        );
end entity;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

architecture rtl of Booth16 is
begin
    process(CLK)
        variable a : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        variable b : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        variable s : std_logic_vector(32 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        variable incre : integer:= 0; 
        variable valid1 : std_logic:= '1';
    begin
        if RST = '1' then
            valid1 := '0';
            valid <= '0';
            s := (others => '0');
            P <= (others => '-');
            a := M;
            s(16 downto 1) := Q;
        elsif rising_edge(CLK) and valid1 = '0' then
            incre := incre + 1;
            if(s(1) = '1' and s(0) = '0') then
                b := s(32 downto 17);
                s(32 downto 17) := b(15 downto 0) - a(15 downto 0);
            elsif (s(1) = '0' and s(0) = '1') then
                b := s(32 downto 17);
                s(32 downto 17) := b(15 downto 0) + a(15 downto 0);
            end if;
            s(31 downto 0) := s(32 downto 1);
        end if;
        if incre = 16 then
            P(31 downto 0) <= s(32 downto 1);
            valid1 := '1';
            valid <= '1';
            incre := 0;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

and the testbench

```
entity Booth16_TB is
end entity;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

architecture rtl of Booth16_TB is
    signal CLK   : std_logic;
    signal RST   : std_logic;
    signal M     : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal Q     : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal valid : std_logic;
    signal P     : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin
    DUT: entity work.Booth16 port map (
        CLK => CLK,
        RST => RST,
        valid => valid,
        M => M,
        Q => Q,
        P => P
    );

    CLK_prc: process begin
        CLK <= '0', '1' after 10 ns;
        wait for 20 ns;
    end process;

    RST_prc: process begin
        CLK <= '1', '0' after 20 ns;
        wait;
    end process;

    M <= b"0100_0000_0000_0000";
    Q <= b"0100_0000_0000_0000";
end architecture;
```

... what can I say about this... it's just not the right approach on many levels...

- using `variable`s in a clocked statement. This is possible, but very error prone. Use `signal`s
- using `std_logic_vector` arithmetic... just don't
- asynchonous reset. It's possible, but you have to know what you're doing.
- the final `if incre = 16`... part is not clocked, nor reset... this would give very weird logic. And once `incre` is 16 you whole fsm is locked... `RST` will not have the desired effect anymore.
- you're using the reset signal for control... also not a good design decision.

You overwrite the same signals and variables multiple times in the same process. Easy to get lost there.

A better design would imho be:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Booth16 is
    port (
        CLK   : in  std_logic;
        RST   : in  std_logic;
        start : in  std_logic;
        M     : in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        Q     : in  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        valid : out std_logic;
        P     : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
        );
end entity;

architecture rtl of Booth16 is
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    signal a : unsigned(15 downto 0);
    signal b : unsigned(15 downto 0);
    signal s : unsigned(32 downto 0);
    signal incre : integer:= 16; 
    signal run : std_logic := '0';
begin
    process(CLK)
    begin
        if rising_edge(CLK) then
            if RST = '1' then
                a <= (others => '0');
                b <= (others => '0');
                s <= (others => '0');
                incre <= 0;
                run <= '0';
                valid <= '0';
                P <= (others => '0');
            else
                if run = '1' then
                    if incre = 0 then
                        P(31 downto 0) <= std_logic_vector(s(32 downto 1));
                        run <= '0';
                        valid <= '1';
                    else 
                        if(s(1) = '1' and s(0) = '0') then
                            b <= s(32 downto 17);
                            s(32 downto 17) <= (b(15 downto 0) - a(15 downto 0));
                        elsif (s(1) = '0' and s(0) = '1') then
                            b <= (s(32 downto 17));
                            s(32 downto 17) <= (b(15 downto 0) + a(15 downto 0));
                        end if;
                        s(31 downto 0) <= s(32 downto 1);
                        incre <= incre - 1; -- counting down can save logic
                    end if;
                elsif start = '1' then
                    a <= unsigned(M);
                    s <= (others => '0');
                    s(16 downto 1) <= unsigned(Q);
                    incre <= 16;
                    run <= '1';
                    valid <= '0';
                    P <= (others => '0');
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

But of course this code doesn't work as intended, because your code relies on immediate assignment of variables... which doesn't work that way for signals! So you'll have to redesign. A good exercise! :)

Comment: Thank you very much, the assignment was turned in, but after reviewing your code, brushing up on my signal, variable assignment I feel much better in the course. Thank you for this example, it was passed on to other class mates for revision we all appreciate.